# Python : subprocess is not working in crontab

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, subprocess, lz4

**extract.py**:

```
def extract_lz4(lz4_path):
    status = subprocess.call(["lz4", "-df", lz4_path], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    log.info("In Extract fun STATUS : {}".format(status))
    if not status:
        log.info("Extract Successful of {}".format(lz4_path))
        return status
    else:
        log.info("Extract Successful of {}".format(lz4_path))
        return status
```

**Main.py**:

```
 lz4_file = '<path-to-lz4-file>/ly486imc83e0v9a7-23-telnet-banner-full_ipv4-20180515T040003-zmap-results.csv.lz4'

 extract_status = extract_lz4_task(lz4_file)
 log.info("extract_status : {}".format(extract_status))
```

when I called main file by `python <path-to-file>/main.py` it will extract successfully.
But *when I put this in crontab it will not extract*.

**crontab -e**:

```
* * * * * python <path-to-file>/main.py
```

Is there anything I'm missing? any Help will be appreciate

Comment: `lz4` isn't in the path maybe? crontab doesn't have the same paths set as your account. also check if `lz4_path` is correct. also, check the exception and log it in a file so "it will not extract" will become "I have the traceback of the error"

Comment: extract_lz4 does not return a value, so extract_status will be None, now see it does ... edited  mean while ?

Comment: what is the cron output when you run it ? If it is a path issue you might try in the cron : ( cd <the_path_where_is_works_manually>; python <yourscript>)

Comment: Subprocess return 0, Doesn't mean that that process will success? And I provide full `lz4_path`

Comment: Append this to your crontab entry: > /tmp/logfile 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

Try debug Your cron with:

```
tail /var/log/cron
```

Or add logfile

```
$ crontab -e
  * * * * * python <path-to-file>/main.py >> <path-to-file>/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: `cron.log` is saving all data from csv. How is that happening?

Comment: That's mean main.py send data from csv as function output.

Comment: `main..py` is just used to call extract function so how can it send data from csv before extract it?

Comment: After deeper look I thing it's all about `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` and `2>&1` in our case it's working as `1>&2`, so please try type from cmd without cron `python <path-to-file>/main.py >> <path-to-file>/cron.log`.

Comment: same output as cron. `cron.log` is full of with csv data

Comment: Do You read the lz4 manual? Try run lz4 -df filename, and checkout the output. From manpage:

-f, --[no-]force

 This option has several effects:
•
If the target file already exists, overwrite it without prompting.
•
When used with --decompress and lz4 cannot recognize the type of the source file, copy the source file as is to standard output. This allows lz4cat --force to be used like cat(1) for files that have not been compressed with lz4.

Comment: but I can run same script from terminal and it decompress. What is your suggestion?

Comment: I don't know lz4 at all, but I recommend try debug why lz4 cannot recognize the type of the source file. There is -t option for test the integrity of compressed .lz4 files. It could be good start point. Or use only -d flag for testing